# Django - get latest price for each product and put in a query set in order to render in a template

Tags: django, join, django-queryset

I have 3 models:

```
class Chemicals(models.Model):
    id_chemical = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    id_supplier = models.ForeignKey(Suppliers, null=True, on_delete = models.CASCADE)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False, null=False)
    [...]

class Suppliers(models.Model):
    id_supplier = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    [...]

class Prices(models.Model):
    id_chemical=models.ForeignKey(Chemicals, null=False, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='prezzo')
    price=models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False, default=0)
    price_date=models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today)
```

I need to get the latest price by date and use it in a queryset to show it in a template. I tried this solution:

```py
def price_list(request,pk):
    supplier = get_object_or_404(Suppliers, pk=pk)
    chemicals_list = Chemicals.objects.filter(id_supplier=pk)
    chem_price = chemicals_list
    qs = Prices.objects.all()

    prova = qs.values('id_chemical').annotate(latest_price=Max('price_date'))       
    qs = qs.filter(price_date__in=prova.values('latest_price').order_by('-  price_date')).filter(id_chemical__id_supplier=pk)

    context = {'supplier': supplier, 'chemicals_list': chemicals_list, 'qs': qs, 'chem_price': chem_price}
    return render(request, "chemicals/price_list.html", context)
```

Now I have what I need but if I want to show it in a template I have some problem. I tried to do this:

```
<tbody>
{% for chemical in chem_price %}
<tr>                                    
<td><a href="{% url 'chemicals:single-product' pk=chemical.id_chemical %}">{{ chemical.description }}</a></td>                            
<td>{{ qs.price }}</td>                                                      
<td>{{ chemical.cov }}</td>
{% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

Whit this solution, in template I see the same price for all products.
I need to take some columns of my chemicals model, add latest price and show in a table row in a template.

Comment: Can you update your code for the `price_list` view and show where `chem_price` comes from?

Comment: I update the code with chem_price. Sorry for this.

Comment: So for each Chemical instance, do you want to show the latest price_date?

Comment: Yes. This is what I need.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple points which I noticed that may need to be considered for better understanding of your code to yourself and potentially help you solve your problem as well.

- Class names should not be in plural form, as a class definition indicates a single entity (instance) of itself. So instead of <s>`class Chemicals`</s>, use `class Chemical`, and similarly everywhere.
- The `id_chemical` attribute that you intend to use as primary key of your `class Chemicals`, can be simply named as `id`, as the attribute itself is inside Chemicals class, therefore we don't need to mention it in its attribute name too. Similarly for other non-relation attributes.
- The `id_supplier` attribute that you intend to use as foreign key of your `class Chemicals` for relation with `class Suppliers`, can be simply named as `supplier`, as when you'll access this foreign key for an instance of Chemical, the attribute can be used to access the attributes of the related Supplier instance. So, for instance, instead of looking like the following

  ```py
  chemical = Chemicals.objects.get(id=pk)
  return chemical.id_supplier.company_name
  ```

  it will look better and will be more
  understandable like following

  ```py
  chemical = Chemical.objects.get(id=pk)
  return chemical.supplier.company_name
  ```

Similarly, there can be other improvements which will make your code more readable and understandable to everyone, and especially to you.

Now coming to your actual problem. Considering the recommendations in the aforementioned points and assuming that I've understood your problem correctly, your html code may need the following changes to work properly

- You're not closing your `<tr>` tag.
- There's no `chem_price` object defined anywhere
- The `chemical` object that you're using in `for` loop is actually a `class Price` object, so can't use `{{chemical.description}}` directly.

Other factors, like improper context data can also affect your desired outcome.

Comment: I update the code and put the chem_price. I'm sure I can write down my question in better way. I'm sorry for this. My template is working well about the list of chemicals. The problem is the price, coming from another model.

Answer (score 0):

I found a possible solution.
In my Chemicals model, I put a method to get the last price

```
class Chemicals(models.Model):
     [...]

     def get_price(self):
        price_object = Prices.objects.all()     
          partial_qs=price_object.values('id_chemical').annotate(latest_price=Max('price_date'))
        price_object=price_object.filter(price_date__in=partial_qs.values('latest_price').order_by('-price_date')).get(id_chemical=self.id_chemical)
        price = price_object.price        
        return price
```

Then, in my template:

```
{% for chemical in chemicals_list %}
     <tr>                                    
     <td><a href="{% url 'chemicals:single-product' pk=chemical.id_chemical %}">{{ chemical.description }}</a></td>                                                   
     <td>{{ chemical.get_price }}</td>                            
     <td>{{ chemical.cov }}</td>
     </tr>
     {% endfor %}
```

I hope this may be the right way. Now I have what I was searching for.
Thanks for the suggestions you gave me.